# When sending SMS more than once with iOS 4.3 MFMessageComposeViewController always has data of the first message

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I'm using MFMessageComposeViewController to send SMS from iPhone devices.

This works correctly with iOS 5 and later.

But in iOS 4.3 I can send SMS only once correctly. All next attempts present me MFMessageComposeViewController with data from first SMS.

I'm using Xcode 4.3.2 with ARC enabled.

Comment: your `MFMessageComposeViewController` does not dealloc after sending & dismissal. Try to set it to `null` and re-create it in next SMS sending.

Comment: I'm allocating it again in method each time i want to send SMS

Comment: are you sure you are allocating the same controller? try to set it to `null` and retry .

Comment: Ok found the problem. I had to call [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; in - (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result

Comment: correct ! please make it as an answer .

Answer (score 0):

By Shivan Raptor's request:

There is a need to call

```
[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

in -

```
(void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
```